# Change selected option from multiple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the selected < option > for multiple < select > by index.

I know for only one < select > there is:

```
$('select[name="test"] option').eq(val).prop('selected', true);
```

Now that works only, when there is one and only one < select > with name = "test". With multiple I changed my Code to this:

```
$('select[name="test"]').each(function (index, value) {
  $(value).select('options').eq(val).prop('selected', true));
});
```

But that doesn't work, any help?

Comment: `.select` does not do that -- it's an [event/event handler](https://api.jquery.com/select/). Secondly, where is `val` defined?

Comment: The index value, should've named it `index` to make it more clear, it's a number defined beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `select` to `find`, like:

```
$('select[name="test"]').each(function (index, value) {
  $(value).find('options').eq(val).prop('selected', true));
});
```

But this won't work unless `val` is defined somewhere... is it? And `val` would be the index of the `<option>` not the value of it. For instance, if `val = 0`, the first option would be selected, if `val=1`, the second option would be selected, etc (it's a zero-based index).

Comment: `find` was the right method, thanks!
I should've renamed `val` to `index` so that it's more clear you're right..

Answer (score 1):

Given that `val` is the index of the `<option>` element you wish to have selected, you can simply use:

```
// selecting all <option> elements which are the relevant nth-child
// of their parent <select> elements with the name=test:
$('select[name=test] option:nth-child(' + (val + 1) + ')')
    // setting the selected property to true of all <option> elements
    // matching the given selector:
    .prop('selected', true);
```

```js
$('#demo').on('change', function (e) {
  var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  $('select[name=test] option:nth-child(' + (val + 1) + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
input, select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Enter the <em>index</em> of the <code>&lt;option&gt;</code> you wish to select:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="3" value="0" step="1" id="demo" />
</label>

<select name="test">
  <option>Index: 0</option>
  <option>Index: 1</option>
  <option>Index: 2</option>
  <option>Index: 3</option>
</select>

<select name="test">
  <option>Index: 0</option>
  <option>Index: 1</option>
  <option>Index: 2</option>
  <option>Index: 3</option>
</select>

<select name="test">
  <option>Index: 0</option>
  <option>Index: 1</option>
  <option>Index: 2</option>
  <option>Index: 3</option>
</select>
```

The reason for the `(val + 1)` is because JavaScript is zero-based whereas CSS selectors, using `:nth-child()`, is one-based. This is potentially problematic, however, if your `<option>` elements are contained within `<optgroup>` parent elements:

```js
$('#demo').on('change', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  $('select[name=test] option:nth-child(' + (val + 1) + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
input,
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Enter the <em>index</em> of the <code>&lt;option&gt;</code> you wish to select:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="7" value="0" step="1" id="demo" />
</label>

<select name="test">
  <optgroup label="first group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 1</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 2</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 3</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="second group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 5</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 6</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 7</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select name="test">
  <optgroup label="first group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 9</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 10</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 11</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 12</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="second group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 13</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 14</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 15</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 16</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is because the `prop()` method (as do most jQuery methods that can act on multiple elements/nodes) internally loops over the contents of the collection upon which it was chained, and in the above illustration there are two `<option>` elements - one within each `<optgroup>` - that matches the `:nth-child()` selector, and in the loop the last element to match the selector is given the `selected` property. Also, because we're using `:nth-child()` to select elements there's no way to explicitly select the `<option>`s from the second `<optgroup>`, since we're selecting based on the index of an element within its parent, so selecting the element of index `5` won't match any element, since there are only four `<option>` elements in each `<optgroup>`.

In this situation, the `each()` would be required, or at least it would be easiest to use the `each()` method:

```
$('#demo').on('change', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  // selecting the <select> element with the name of 'test',
  // iterating over each of them:
  $('select[name=test]').each(function() {
    // using plain JavaScript at this point, for simplicity.

    // this.options is a HTMLOptionsCollection of all <option>
    // elements contained within the <select> ('this'), here 
    // using array-notation to access the required <option> 
    // from that HTMLOptionsCollection, and setting its 
    // selected property to true:
    this.options[val].selected = true;
  });
});
```

```js
$('#demo').on('change', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  $('select[name=test]').each(function() {
    this.options[val].selected = true;
  });
});
```

```css
input,
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Enter the <em>index</em> of the <code>&lt;option&gt;</code> you wish to select:
  <input type="number" min="0" max="7" value="0" step="1" id="demo" />
</label>

<select name="test">
  <optgroup label="first group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 1</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 2</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 3</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="second group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 5</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 6</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 7</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select name="test">
  <optgroup label="first group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 9</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 10</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 11</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 12</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="second group">
    <option>nth-child: 1, option element: 13</option>
    <option>nth-child: 2, option element: 14</option>
    <option>nth-child: 3, option element: 15</option>
    <option>nth-child: 4, option element: 16</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
  - [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).